# (SQL ORACLE) How to generate html output, given select statement?

Tags: html, sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm working on oracle and taking report from database Oracle.

```
SELECT OPERATION, OBJECT_TYPE, CPU_COST, IO_COST FROM SYS.V_$SQL_PLAN;
```

I want to take a html output in oracle. I have this table in output but I want to see html formate. Is there any way to see that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from [SQL* Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/apd.htm#SQPUG157)

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SELECT OPERATION, OBJECT_TYPE, CPU_COST, IO_COST FROM SYS.V_$SQL_PLAN;
```

Check [This link](http://houseofbrick.com/creating-html-reports-using-sqlplus/) for more options to format the output as desired.

Comment: Thank you but I need in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER.